# Access 3 asynctask APIs from a single activity

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask

I have 3 categories in my android application. For that I have 3 API calls to make so that I can load my all the items. I have to access the same API url but I have to send the appropriate `categoryCode`, so that I can get the required data item through the API. By following that method I have loaded items to application. Now I'm trying to implement the search function and when I try to access all these 3 APIs to load the data then it doesn't happen. It loads the items belongs to only 1 API. I read one activity can load items belongs to only one API at a time. So how can I load all the items.

How is it possible to get the items which I loaded in different categories. If I could access that then I'll be able to get it from there without loading APIs once again.

Really appreciate any advises to achieve this task.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the Json string in a static string variable of your project and can access the same inside the activity

Comment: thanks for the idea, I was able to implement an answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe your search api should be just call only,n filtering should be done based on category with one api call setting cat as rest param,hitting db three times for filtering ,I dont think is recommended.

Comment: I don't have single search API, I have 3 different API's to load items belongs to 3 different categories. Search should get all the items loaded using those 3 APIs